# Alomafire: getting response body from DataRequest Object during request failure

Tags: alamofire, rxalamofire

How can we get response body from DataRequest object? I am using RxAlomafire.request method for making http calls. Need some data from response body when http request fails.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: I can access HTTPURLResponse object from it. But could not find a relevant method to access the response body from it.